# find numbers in text using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a way to extract the numbers (xxx.xxxx) from this textfile (was a gml cityJson file):

```
   </bldg:lod2Solid>
      <bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>
        <gml:MultiCurve>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.98 5808526.986 68.01 371139.991 5808526.991 68.01 371140 5808526.995 68.01 371140.01 5808527 68.01 371140.378 5808527.169 68.01</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.378 5808527.169 68.01 371140.809 5808527.245 68.01</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.809 5808527.245 68.01 371141 5808527.229 68.01 371141.212 5808527.212 68.008 371141.245 5808527.209 68.006</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.245 5808527.209 68.006 371141.657 5808527.063 67.986</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.657 5808527.063 67.986 371141.75 5808527 67.98 371141.899 5808526.899 67.977 371142 5808526.83 67.973 371142.019 5808526.817 67.974</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.019 5808526.817 67.974 371142.306 5808526.486 67.993</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.306 5808526.486 67.993 371142.365 5808526.365 67.997 371142.499 5808526.094 67.988</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.499 5808526.094 67.988 371142.518 5808526 67.985 371142.586 5808525.665 67.998</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.561 5808525.228 67.982 371142.581 5808525.581 68.001 371142.586 5808525.665 67.998</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.386 5808524.801 67.992 371142.468 5808525 67.979 371142.561 5808525.228 67.982</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.107 5808524.435 68.03 371142.386 5808524.801 67.992</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.743 5808524.152 68.057 371142 5808524.352 68.043 371142.107 5808524.435 68.03</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.318 5808523.973 68.077 371141.382 5808524 68.075 371141.743 5808524.152 68.057</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.862 5808523.91 68.09 371140.918 5808523.918 68.09 371141 5808523.929 68.089 371141.318 5808523.973 68.077</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.404 5808523.968 68.096 371140.862 5808523.91 68.09</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.977 5808524.141 68.095 371140 5808524.132 68.096 371140.094 5808524.094 68.097 371140.325 5808524 68.097 371140.404 5808523.968 68.096</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.61 5808524.419 68.072 371139.977 5808524.141 68.095</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.326 5808524.782 68.063 371139.526 5808524.526 68.065 371139.61 5808524.419 68.072</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371137.811 5808525.146 68.103 371138 5808525.101 68.111 371138.081 5808525.081 68.113 371138.419 5808525 68.095 371138.887 5808524.887 68.074 371139 5808524.86 68.06 371139.326 5808524.782 68.063</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371137.811 5808525.146 68.103 371137.896 5808525.896 68.037 371137.908 5808526 68.035 371137.995 5808526.769 68.015</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371137.995 5808526.769 68.015 371138 5808526.769 68.015 371138.741 5808526.741 68.015 371139 5808526.731 68.015 371139.643 5808526.707 68.016</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.643 5808526.707 68.016 371139.98 5808526.986 68.01</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
        </gml:MultiCurve>
      </bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>
      <bldg:boundedBy>
        <bldg:WallSurface gml:id="UUID_776cbf08-4447-4c77-8c77-4ea39b283a81">
          <core:creationDate>2022-03-03</core:creationDate>
          <bldg:lod2MultiSurface>
            <gml:MultiSurface gml:id="UUID_3d4e234e-add8-43d9-b90c-abbcbbe6073c">
              <gml:surfaceMember>
```

my plan was to first find everything between       `<bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>`
and `</bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>` via regex `/<bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>(.*?)<\/bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>/g` but it is not finding anything...
then the plan was to extract the numbers via regex: `\d+\.\d+`  to extract all numbers which are xxx.xxx is also not working :/

What am I doing wrong? or would there be a better way to do that?

thanks a lot for help!

Comment: which is the environment you are using to perform such an action? I ask because the first stage of that process would be better fulfilled using a parser over the tags and then use regular expression on tag content. Are you using a text editor or the process may involve javascript also?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply! i will have to do this in typescript / javascript later. i would love to use a parser, but i very likely get an incomplete gml file - so that a parser would have a hard time. i thought a regex would be the more reliable way (but i am just terrible with regex...)

Comment: actually the regex is a much more unreliable way to parse a file like that. That's why the parser is better (parse->parser). The problem is that if you have a invalid input file the output will be totally garbage. Both using parser or regex

Comment: so i guess i need to work on the input files then ^^ why did you ask if i am going to use javascript? whats the difference in regex? or was the question just bevause of the possible use of a parser?

Comment: because if js was an option a more solid solution that was not going to provoke a flame among anyone reading it, would be using DOMParser over the xml and then just use the returned object to fetch all the interested nodes to retrieve and process their content using regular expressions. Now the problem is that such xml should be valid for the parser to not throw any error.

Answer (score 1):

Since regex are not reliable at parsing nested contents like an xml document, the best option to better deal with your expectation would be using the `DOMParser` object as long as Javascript will be the runtime to perform this job.

Here I show a function that will parse a given text content being an xml and will retrieve all its `posList` nodes inside each `lod2TerrainIntersection` parent node. The result will be returned as an array of string for each parent element.

So that the `posList` tag value will be extracted and you'll have all those "numbers" isolated as values of an array. Now once you have those values you can parse them as you best prefer.

```
function parseContent(xmlcontent){
  //parse the xml document
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlcontent, "text/xml");

  //select elements having tagname bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection
  const nodes_lod2TerrainIntersection = xml.getElementsByTagName('bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection');
  
  //fetch the result as an array of collections of posList values for each parent container
  const values = [...nodes_lod2TerrainIntersection].map(parentNode => {
    //select all the descendant being gml:postList
    const nodes_posList = parentNode.getElementsByTagName('gml:posList');
    //return the array of values coming from all those nodes
    return [...nodes_posList].map( node => node.textContent );    
  });
  
  return values;
}
```

This is an example of array returned for a single parent node:

```
[
    "371139.98 5808526.986 68.01 371139.991 5808526.991 68.01 371140 5808526.995 68.01 371140.01 5808527 68.01 371140.378 5808527.169 68.01",
    "371140.378 5808527.169 68.01 371140.809 5808527.245 68.01",
    "371140.809 5808527.245 68.01 371141 5808527.229 68.01 371141.212 5808527.212 68.008 371141.245 5808527.209 68.006",
    ...
]
```

```js
function parseContent(xmlcontent){
  //parse the xml document
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlcontent, "text/xml");

  //select elements having tagname bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection
  const nodes_lod2TerrainIntersection = xml.getElementsByTagName('bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection');
  
  //fetch the result as an array of collections of posList values for each parent container
  const values = [...nodes_lod2TerrainIntersection].map(parentNode => {
    //select all the descendant being gml:postList
    const nodes_posList = parentNode.getElementsByTagName('gml:posList');
    //return the array of values coming from all those nodes
    return [...nodes_posList].map( node => node.textContent );    
  });
  
  return values;
}

//I added a root element to your xml just to add some xml consistency
const filecontent = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<core:Model
  xmlns:bldg="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:core="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">

 <bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>
        <gml:MultiCurve>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.98 5808526.986 68.01 371139.991 5808526.991 68.01 371140 5808526.995 68.01 371140.01 5808527 68.01 371140.378 5808527.169 68.01</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.378 5808527.169 68.01 371140.809 5808527.245 68.01</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.809 5808527.245 68.01 371141 5808527.229 68.01 371141.212 5808527.212 68.008 371141.245 5808527.209 68.006</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.245 5808527.209 68.006 371141.657 5808527.063 67.986</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.657 5808527.063 67.986 371141.75 5808527 67.98 371141.899 5808526.899 67.977 371142 5808526.83 67.973 371142.019 5808526.817 67.974</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.019 5808526.817 67.974 371142.306 5808526.486 67.993</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.306 5808526.486 67.993 371142.365 5808526.365 67.997 371142.499 5808526.094 67.988</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.499 5808526.094 67.988 371142.518 5808526 67.985 371142.586 5808525.665 67.998</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.561 5808525.228 67.982 371142.581 5808525.581 68.001 371142.586 5808525.665 67.998</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.386 5808524.801 67.992 371142.468 5808525 67.979 371142.561 5808525.228 67.982</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371142.107 5808524.435 68.03 371142.386 5808524.801 67.992</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.743 5808524.152 68.057 371142 5808524.352 68.043 371142.107 5808524.435 68.03</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371141.318 5808523.973 68.077 371141.382 5808524 68.075 371141.743 5808524.152 68.057</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.862 5808523.91 68.09 371140.918 5808523.918 68.09 371141 5808523.929 68.089 371141.318 5808523.973 68.077</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371140.404 5808523.968 68.096 371140.862 5808523.91 68.09</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.977 5808524.141 68.095 371140 5808524.132 68.096 371140.094 5808524.094 68.097 371140.325 5808524 68.097 371140.404 5808523.968 68.096</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.61 5808524.419 68.072 371139.977 5808524.141 68.095</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.326 5808524.782 68.063 371139.526 5808524.526 68.065 371139.61 5808524.419 68.072</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371137.811 5808525.146 68.103 371138 5808525.101 68.111 371138.081 5808525.081 68.113 371138.419 5808525 68.095 371138.887 5808524.887 68.074 371139 5808524.86 68.06 371139.326 5808524.782 68.063</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371137.811 5808525.146 68.103 371137.896 5808525.896 68.037 371137.908 5808526 68.035 371137.995 5808526.769 68.015</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371137.995 5808526.769 68.015 371138 5808526.769 68.015 371138.741 5808526.741 68.015 371139 5808526.731 68.015 371139.643 5808526.707 68.016</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
          <gml:curveMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:posList srsDimension="3">371139.643 5808526.707 68.016 371139.98 5808526.986 68.01</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:curveMember>
        </gml:MultiCurve>
      </bldg:lod2TerrainIntersection>

</core:Model>`;  

const values = parseContent(filecontent);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: that is one increadible answer!! i will definitely go that way once i have fixed my xml files to be valid and complete files. Do you have any suggestion for a simple xml parsing solution in nodejs since DOMParser is not available in node?
Thanks again!!

Comment: @HannesF ... [npmjs DOMParser search](https://www.npmjs.com/search?ranking=optimal&q=DOMParser)